# About Spring Rest Date

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, timezone, spring-rest

I am using spring boot, hibernate.I also have a class for time values inherited from the DATE class.I use this inherited class in my entities.

A column value in the database is '08 / 01/2020 18:02:22 '.
When I get this value with the postman, it appears as '2020-01-08T15: 02: 22.000 + 0000' at the rest client.
When '2020-01-08T15: 02: 22.000 + 0000' is sent from rest client, the column value appears as '08 / 01/2020 18:02:22 '.(correct value)

the value should appear as "dd / MM / yyyy HH: mm: ss" everywhere. How can I do this?

constructor metod in inherited date class:

```
this.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat(SPRING_DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN).parse(str).getTime())
```

Comment: Why should it? That is just the `toString` of a data. Why should a date suddenly be formatted because it was parsed with a specific format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a way to modify the timestamp value when it's serialized from a Java object to JSON or XML.

The library responsible for this is Jackson and the object actually doing it is called ObjectMapper. By default it will be serialized in the ISO-8601 notation.
If you want to change the way it will output, you can either dive right into coding defining an`Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` bean (see below), or if you use Spring Boot you can add to your `application.properties` the following entry;

```
spring.jackson.date-format=dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

There is however one drawback and that is that this does not support Java8 Date and Time classes. So it won't affect the way it serializes `java.time.LocalDate` or `java.time.Localtime`, or it's combined `java.time.LocalDateTime` objects. It only works for `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar`.

If you want Java8 support then your only option is getting your hands dirty like so

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
    final String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    final String dateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    return builder -> {
        builder.simpleDateFormat(dateTimeFormat);
        builder.serializers(new LocalDateSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat)));
        builder.serializers(new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeFormat)));
    };
}
```

As I final note, if you only want to alter the output of certain fields and not all, you can annotate specific fields in your DTO with Jackson's `@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat` annotation.